# linking code from a separate document to work on another page

Tags: javascript

I have taken script from a webpage document I have made and I have saved onto a notepad     document with the extension *.js*.

I would like to now know how I can reference this .js file from the current page that I have created so that the script will run on that page without the actual code being there, just the reference link.

Comment: You should clarify what you have tried, and remember that the process on how code gets to files is not relevant. It's enough to say, "I've put a webpage script into a file name blah.js" This lets you bring to light what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be a reference link. There are other techniques besides the standard, but they all rely on linkage. You can't beat the linkage. You can't stop the linkage. You mus succumb to the linkage.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js" />
```

Comment: used this method and nothing happens when i try to use the javascript functions                                                            <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/help_page_code.js"></script> im using thos over usb webserver when i go to open the page still i get nothing i know that the code is right but something is a miss

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the web works? You might be able to use some sort of developer tool to execute arbitrary javascript from a file when the page loads, but that would just be overriding the default way the web works.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to do :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="URI_TO_DIR/extension.js"></script>
```

see [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html) about embedding a javascript file

if script is on your computer, it will of course not be accessible on the web, for that you'd need a webserver or a webspace

Comment: Thanks I have not tried it yet as i have come across another problem I looked at my file saved as.js and its saying there are code errors which is weird because when it is in html form on the actual page there are no errors it's fine. I copy n paste it into a.js file and its coming up with syntax errors all over the damn place ????

Comment: if it is in html like <script>the js code</script> you need to put in the js file "the js code" only. if you do that and code was ok at start, you should not get syntax errors, I often use http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home to have better info on what is the error

Answer (score 0):

You can include an external JavaScript using a script tag with a src attribute. For example, something like
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascriptfile.js"></script>` should do what I think you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks I have not tried it yet as i have come across another problem I looked at my file saved as.js and its saying there are code errors which is weird because when it is in html form on the actual page there are no errors it's fine. I copy n paste it into a.js file and its coming up with syntax errors all over the damn place ????